# Python runs weird with ctrl+F5 on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 17.5.5.
Below is my code.

```
with open('routers.txt', 'r') as routers_txt:
    router_line_list = routers_txt.read().splitlines()

print(router_line_list)

for router_line in router_line_list:
    print(router_line)
for router_line in router_line_list:
    print('a')
```

And routers.txt is next.

```
Name,802.11 Specification,Memory,Price
NetEdge X12,Wi-Fi 6,64 MiB,199.99
StreamLink AC10,802.11ac,512 KiB,$89.99
AirTech XL,ax,1 MiB,54.99
LinkWave N2,802.11n,2 GiB,149.99
WiZone 5000,Wi-Fi 5,16 MiB,79.99
UltraWave AC8,802.11ac,2048 KiB,119.99
FastLink AC4,ac,4 MiB,179.99
WaveSwift X20,802.11ax,32 MiB,69.99
MaxNet 8000,WiFi 6,8 MiB,249.99
SwiftWave AX20,ax,2 MiB,39.99
AirConnect X16,Wi-Fi 6,128 MiB,299.99
NetStream AX1,802.11ax,1024 MiB,129.99
SwiftLink 400,ax,512 KiB,79.99
TechPro N6,802.11n,4 GiB,199.99
NetWave 3000,WiFi5,32 MiB,109.99
AirLink AC2,802.11ac,4096 MiB,$149.99
MaxWave AC12,ac,16 MiB,229.99
StreamX AX5,802.11ax,8 MiB,99.99
SwiftNet X10,Wi-Fi 6,4 GiB,349.99
NetLink AX3,ax,48 MiB,59.99
```

Everything is alright when debugging with F5.
[Debugging with F5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wJ4m.png)

But there's a problem with ctrl+F5.
[Running with ctrl+F5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDJ3x.png)

I don't know why these things are happening.

Can anyone know what's going on?

I tried recovering visual studio on 17.6.2.
But it still making problem.
So, I rollbacked to 17.5.5 but problem still exists.

Comment: have you tried the same in an different IDE.  `vs code` for example ?

Comment: I haven't tried that but this seems to be a problem with visual studio, I guess.